# Interior and closure of a set

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

A question in the textbook is

Show that $\overline{A} =\{x \in X:B(x,r) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for every $r>0\}$

The solution in the textbook goes on to show that $d (x,A) = 0$ and then prove the statement using this.

I am not clear as to why following simple proof is not valid:

Let x $\in \overline{A}$. Therefore either $x\in A$ or $x\in \partial(A)$.

If $x\in A$, then $\exists B(x,r)$ such that $B(x,r) \subset A$

Therefore $B(x,r) \cap A \neq \emptyset $

If $x \in \partial(A)$, then $B(x,r)$ contains points from $A$ and $A^c$.
Therefore again  $B(x,r) \cap A \neq \emptyset $

Since $x$ is an arbitrary point, and for $x \in A$ or $\partial(A)$ the said intersection is not $\emptyset$, required proof is complete.

Request guide as whether this proof is acceptable

Comment: So $\overline A$ denotes the interior or the closure of $A$?

Comment: It indicates closure of A

Comment: It is not necessarily true that if $x\in A$, there is an $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq A$; this is the case iff $x$ is in the interior of $A$. If one has shown that $A=(\operatorname{int}A)\cup\operatorname{bdry}A$, one can replace the $x\in A$ case with $x\in\operatorname{int}A$ to get a correct argument that $$\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq\{x\in X:B(x,r)\cap A\ne\varnothing\text{ for each }r>0\}\,,$$ but it is still necessary to prove the opposite inclusion.